# Difference between comments in Python, # and """

Tags: python

Starting to program in Python, I see some scripts with comments using `#` and `""" comments """`.

What is the difference between these two ways to comment?

Comment: single line or multiple lines. suggestion: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best thing would be to read *[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)*, but since it is longish, here
is a three-liner:

- Comments start with # and are not part of the code.
- String (delimited by """ """) is actually called a `docstring` and is used on special places for defined purposes (briefly: the first thing in a module or function describing the module or function) and is actually accessible in the code (so it is a part of the program; it is not a comment).

Answer (score 3):

Triple quotes is a way to create a multi-line string and or comment:

```
"""
Descriptive text here
"""
```

Without assigning to a variable is a none operation that some versions of Python will completely ignore.
[PEP 8 suggests when to use block comment/strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments), and I personally follow a format like this:

*[Example Google Style Python Docstrings](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html)*

Answer (score 2):

The string at the start of a module, class or function is a docstring:

- *[PEP 257 -- Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)*

that can be accessed with `some_obj.__doc__` and is used in `help(...)`. Whether you use `"Returns 42"` or `"""Returns 42"""` is a matter of style, and using the latter one is more common, even for single-line documentation.

A `# comment` is just that, a comment. It cannot be accessed at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The # means the whole line is used for a comment while whatever is in between the two """ quotes is used as comments so you can write comments on multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

As the user in a previous answer stated, the triple quotes are used to comment multiple lines of code while the `#` only comments one line.

Look out though, because you can use the triple quotes for docstrings and such.